# Header issue and Sum up multiple excel rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data with missing header

[image]

I used the following code to add the header

df_output = df_output.rename_axis(['Hour','Input'])

[image]

The output seems to be fine, but when i try to sum up the data based on hour i get the error KeyError: 'Hour'

df_output = df.groupby(['Hour'], as_index=False).sum()

Comment: 'Hour' is an level of the index, not a column. Try `df.groupby(level='Hour', as_index=False).sum()`

Comment: Btw please put your data directly in the description, not as an image. We can't test images, only code. For instance, share the result of `print(df_output.to_dict())` together with `print(df_output)` inside a code block. It's much easier for us to reproduce your problem and help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'Hour' column is currently the index for you dataframe therefore you get the keyword error as the column does is not actually a column in the dataframe.

Try to reset the index first and then group by.

```
df_output = df_output.reset_index()

df_hour_sum = df.groupby(['Hour'], as_index=False).sum()
```